# Category for Single.php on navigation menu does not show highlighted

Tags: wordpress, post, navigation

Is it possible for the single.php post page to show its page category as the current page on the navigation menu? I am creating a twenty twelve theme child theme and have no idea how to fix this.  I assume theres something i need to put in the functions? thanks a lot!

Comment: So the categories that you assign to posts are the same as the main menu?

Comment: yes, they are in the same main menu. For example i have a category called toothbrushes which is in the same menu as the home and about us pages.

Comment: Sounds like you want to get the string value of the current post, then loop through the menu items and see if there is a match. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Thanks for responding Chizzle. That sort of sounds like what I want to do.  I'm a beginner at php and JavaScript so I'm not entirely sure if that will be the way to do it. I could also use breadcrumbs for the viewer to know where they are but it seems that if the current page navigation is highlighted it will make more sense. Hope this info helps